# Android Studio Cannot resolve method setView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem.
I want to make an application with Augmented Images and this is a part of my code:

```
package com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.augmentedimage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.ar.core.AugmentedImage;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.Node;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.math.Vector3;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ViewRenderable;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;


import android.app.Activity;


@SuppressWarnings({"AndroidApiChecker"})
public class AugmentedImageNode extends AnchorNode {

  private static final String TAG = "AugmentedImageNode";

  private AugmentedImage image;

  private static CompletableFuture<ModelRenderable> anzeige;
  private ViewRenderable testrenderable;


  public AugmentedImageNode(Context context) {
    if (anzeige == null) {

      anzeige =
              ViewRenderable.builder()
                      .setView(this, R.layout.test)
                      .build().thenAccept(renderable -> testrenderable = renderable);
    }
  }
```

At this position

```
.setView(this, R.layout.test)
```

I get the error warning : "Cannot resolve method setView(com.google.ar,sceneform.samples.augmentedimage.AugmentedImageNode,int)

Can someone help me please

Comment: You should probably understand the basics of what a Context object is before you try to use the ARCore.

Answer (score 1):

If you reference [The ARCore Reference](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/ViewRenderable.html#builder()), you'll see that the `builder()` of `ViewRenderable` object has a method `setView` but the forst parameter is `context`. Replace your line with `.setView(context, R.layout.test)`

Comment: It stilll dont work. The context was unused so I have delete it.